# Fbgraph Data Querying Meteor 1.3

Tags: javascript, facebook, meteor, npm

While I was using Meteor 1.2 I would use the following code on my server to query user data and friends data:

```
function Facebook(accessToken) {
    this.fb = Meteor.npmRequire('fbgraph');
    this.accessToken = accessToken;
    this.fb.setAccessToken(this.accessToken);
    this.options = {
        timeout: 3000,
        pool: {maxSockets: Infinity},
        headers: {connection: "keep-alive"}
   }
   this.fb.setOptions(this.options);
}
Facebook.prototype.query = function(query, method) {
    var self = this;
    var method = (typeof method === 'undefined') ? 'get' : method;
    var data = Meteor.sync(function(done) {
        self.fb[method](query, function(err, res) {
            done(null, res);
       });
   });
   return data.result;
}

Facebook.prototype.getUserData = function() {
    return this.query('me');
}
Facebook.prototype.getFriendsData = function() {
    return this.query('/me/friends');
}
```

When I was updating my project to Meteor 1.3 I used "meteor npm install --save fbgraph" to install fbgraph but I found that 'npmRequire' no longer worked so I replaced it with 'require' as follows:

```
function Facebook(accessToken) {
    this.fb = require('fbgraph');
    this.accessToken = accessToken;
    this.fb.setAccessToken(this.accessToken);
    this.options = {
        timeout: 3000,
        pool: {maxSockets: Infinity},
        headers: {connection: "keep-alive"}
    }
    this.fb.setOptions(this.options);
}
```

However I still get this error : Exception while invoking method 'getFriendsData' TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'sync'

So my question was whether there is an equivalent function to 'Meteor.sync' of Meteor 1.2 in Meteor 1.3? If not then if there is not how should I change the fb querying code to make it work with Meteor 1.3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to do the trick:

1. First install the run-asnyc npm package

   ```
   $ npm install --save run-async
   ```
2. Use require to initialize the runAsync variable

   ```
   var runAsync = require('run-async');
   ```
3. replace Meteor.sync with runAsync

   ```
   var data = runAsync(function(done) {
       self.fb[method](query, function(err, res) {
           done(null, res);
       });
   });
   ```